# Окончания неопределённых форм глаголов

Tags: глаголы, морфемика, окончания, суффиксы

В русском языке в глаголах неопределенной формы **-ТИ** и **-ТЬ** традиционно считаются окончаниями, а **-ЧЬ** входит в состав корня.
А чем считаются буквосочетания **-ТИСЬ** (или **-ТИ** **-СЬ** отдельно?) в глаголах типа *вес**тись***, *нес**тись***? Да и много ли вообще таких глаголов?
А также вопрос про глаголы примерной формы *достичь, настичь* и пр.: в них **-ЧЬ** входит в состав корня?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Инфинитив (неизменяемая форма глагола) имеет следующие **морфологические показатели: -ТЬ, -ТИ, -СТИ, -ЧЬ,** все они считаются **формообразующими суффиксами**, а не окончаниями: ***видеть, везти, брести, беречь***. В основу они не входят.

Единственным неясным моментом является **показатель -ЧЬ,** который при образовании личных форм чередуется с другими согласными и вроде бы входит в основу: беречь — берегу — бережёт.

2) **Но в этой теме нет единой точки зрения**, поэтому показатели инфинитива могут называться окончаниями, а -ЧЬ включается в основу, например, встречаются такие **разборы онлайн:** нес/ти/сь, нес — корень, ТИ — глагольное окончание, СЬ — постфикс, беречь/ся, беречь — корень, СЯ — суффикс.

3) СЯ/СЬ — **постфикс**, обозначает страдательный или возвратный залог: строиться, одеваться.

Comment: Sharon, простите, пожалуйста, за несвоевременную просьбу: не могли бы вы подсказать, встречалось ли вам в литературе описание -чь в инфинитиве как части корня (при этом не выделялся нулевой суффикс и проч.), т. е. такое, которое считало бы, например, _жечь_ просто корнем. Если встречалось, будьте добры, подскажите, где искать. Большое спасибо!

Comment: В учебнике для вузов ( Рахимкулова, Морфология современного русского языка,2009 год) ЧЬ считается суффиксом. Я посмотрела еще учебник Л.Д. Чеснокова "Современный русский язык", где говорится о двух вариантах разбора (1)печь и  (2)пек-ти: пе-чь). Там говорится о неразложимом сочетании аффикса инфинитива и предшествующего согласного. При этом основа "печь" участвует только в образовании причастия «испеченный», но: испекший, пеку, пёк. (Из этих двух моментов, как мне кажется,  и следует двойное толкование: выделять или не выделять суффикс инфинитива  ЧЬ).

Comment: Розенталь говорит, что группа  Г(К)ТИ преобразовалась в ЧЬ.  (Но тогда опять получается, что  мы можем отнести ЧЬ или к корню, или к суффиксу).  Для сравнения: вед/ти – вес/ти, плет/ти – плес/ти.  В глаголах на СТИ звук С точно  входит в корень, так как  является  результатом фонетических изменений в глаголах на Д/Т для устранения  стечения двух взрывных согласных, а суффикс ТИ сохраняется.

Comment: большое спасибо! Но чтобы однозначно предлагалось выделять только корень печь/жечь и больше ничего, такого нет?

Comment: Ну вот  в первом (более новом)  учебнике ЧЬ названо суффиксом, но подробного разбора там нет. Другого материала мне пока, к сожалению,  не встретилось.

Answer (score 0):

Хотелось бы уточнить по поводу глагола беречь. Чь входит в корень не только в глаголе беречь, а в целой (хоть и небольшой) группе глаголов. В нее входят такие глаголы, как *жечь, лечь, влечь, печь, беречь, стеречь, сечь, течь, стричь, волочь, толочь, мочь, помочь, пренебречь, обречь, наречь, предречь, застичь, настичь, достичь, постичь, помочь, напрячь, впрячь, выпрячь, подпрячь, перепрячь, припрячь, сопрячь, распрячь, отпрячь, упрячь, спрячь.* (А также производные от этих слов: зажечь, поджечь, прижечь, сжечь, поприжечь и т. п). Вхождение -чь в корень связано с историческим развитием восточно-славянского диалекта в праславянскую эпоху. Все эти глаголы имели вид pek-ti, bereg-ti, stereg-ti, где ti было "стандартным" суффиксом инфинитива. Но в процессе развития языка в этих словах сочетания gt, kt превратились в ч (чИ,с последующим отпадением гласного и), таким образом, чь "попало в корень" (а вернее, было в корне исторически, но входило только частью дифтонга), а традиционный суффикс в процессе жизни слова когда-то "отвалился" (видоизменился). В современном  языке исторические явления проявляются в виде чередований в этих глаголах согласных в составе корня к/ч, г/ч : пеку - печь, берегу - беречь, влеку - влечь  и т.п.  Также нужно отметить, что группа этих глаголов непродуктивна, т.е. новые глаголы с подобным "окончанием" в языке не образуются.  (информация подготовлена с использованием учебника Н.М. Шанского, А.Н. Тихонова "Современный русский язык. Ч 2. Словообразование. Морфология", а также "Краткого этимологического словаря" под редакцией С.Г. Бархударова)

Comment: 1) Почему в некоторых источниках выделяют суффикс ЧЬ, для этого есть основания? 2) Беречь - берёг, бережёт. Чередование глухого Ч на звонкие Г/Ж - это нормально для языка? Может, лучше считать, что происходит усечение основы на ЧЬ?

Comment: 1. Можно, пожалуйста, ссылку на источник, где чь называют суффиксом? Если это интернет, то без комментариев. Какой-нибудь авторитетный источник нужен. 2. Чередование ч/г/ж стандартное чередование в корне; закономерное явление, обусловленное палателизацей. Это не усечение, а видоизмение, замена дифтонга с последующим усечением гласного: пек-ти - печи - печь. Но на уровне синхронии (т.е на уровне современного существования языка) усечения нет! Это просто чередование. Обусловленное особенностями истории развития ряда звуковых сочетаний.

Comment: Мне уже дали ссылку  на эту тему  http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part2.htm#3_5 , там рассмотрены два варианта для форманта ЧЬ. Есть учебник для вузов Рахимкулова  "Морфология современного языка", там ЧЬ назван суффиксом. Что касается чередования,  то вопрос такой: у нас встречается чередование глухого Ч и звонких Г/Ж где-нибудь, кроме глаголов?

Answer (score 0):

Что касается "окончаний" инфинитивов -ти и -ть, то, следует отметить, что, действительно, в курсе средней школы существовала тенденция называть эти части начальной формы глагола окончанием. Но в последнее время (уже более 10 лет) в преподавании определяющим является научный подход, в соответствии с которым - ти и -ть являются суффиксами инфинитива. Их трудно назвать окончанием, т.к.  инфинитив не входит в парадигму личных форм глагола, он стоит особняком. 
Конечное -тись в глаголах является, как правило, сочетанием суффикса инфинитива -ти и возвратного постфикса -сь. Это видно по глаголам вестись и нестись, строение которых Вас интересует. В глаголе "вестись" -вес-  - корень (с чередованием с//д: вести - веду ), -ти-  - суффикс, -сь - возвратный постфикс. Нестись: нес -корень, ти - суффикс инфинитива, сь - постфикс. 
Если следовать теории о том, что в инфинитиве мы видим окончание, то, в словах нестись и вестись будет выделяться окончание (ти), а после него - возвратный постфикс. И пусть не смущает наличие постфикса после окончания, ведь, например,  в формах глаголов *занимаюсь* или *вернулась* постфикс находится именно в позиции после окончания.